# How to write negative lookahead in POSIX regex

Tags: c, regex

I'm coding in Mac and I'm setting up a regex with a pattern of an email address format.

Format is [recipientname]@[domain].[top-domain]

**Recipient name:**

-could contain digits, letters, and special characters (limited to ".", "+", "-", and "_")

-should not have consecutive special characters (., +, -, _)

-it should not start/end in special characters.

**Domain name**

-can contain digits, letters, and the "-" character

**Top domain**

-either com, net, or org.

I just don't know how to implement a negative lookaround in c.

The following is the regex I have:

```
^(?!.*(__|--|\+\+|\.\.))(?!.*(_|\-|\+|\.$))[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-+._]*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.(com|net|org)$
```

I got a repetition-operator operand invalid error.

EDIT:
Here's the code I used:

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

regex_t regex;
int status;
char buffer[100];

status=regcomp(&regex, "^(?!.*(__|--|\\+\\+|\\.\\.))(?!.*(_|\\-|\\+|\\.$))[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-+._]*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.(com|net|org)$", REG_EXTENDED);
regerror(status, &regex, buffer, 100);
printf("%s\n", buffer);

}
```

Comment: What regular expression library are you using? Show your code.

Comment: There *are* existing *known correct regexen for email addresses*. What's the use case for producing a possibly broken one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need look-arounds (which `<regex.h>` does not support) to implement your requirements for the recipient name:

- The first character must not be special, so we start with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (a letter or a digit).
- Special characters cannot be repeated and they can't be the last character, which means any special character must always be followed by a letter or digit: `[.+_-][a-zA-Z0-9]`
- Letters and digits can be repeated, i.e. where we have one letter/digit, we can have arbitrarily many: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` ... `[.+_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+` ...
- The recipient name can contain 0 or more special characters, so we have to repeat the second part: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+([.+_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`

And that's it.

---

`(_|\-|\+|\.$)` (from your look-ahead pattern) is broken anyway: It only anchors `\.` (the other alternatives are not anchored), and it anchors to the end of the whole string, when what you really want is to anchor to the end of the recipient name.

Besides, your pattern matches things that are not valid email addresses (e.g. `a@---.com`) and rejects many valid addresses (e.g. `f*ck@example.com`, `jdoe@support.example.com`, `a@[127.0.0.1]`).